# Seeking assistance with @tanstack/react-table v8.9.1 filtering implementation

Tags: reactjs, react-table, react-table-v8

I'm currently facing difficulties with filters in @tanstack/react-table version 8.9.1 and could really use some help.

In my project, I have created four columns that can be sorted alphabetically in ascending or descending order. Additionally, I've implemented a functionality to edit each row. I approached the editable table in a different manner, as I thought this approach would help reduce the number of HTTP requests required.

However, I seem to be missing something in the implementation of the filtering functionality, as it's not working as intended. I've attempted several different approaches, but I haven't been able to resolve the issue.

To provide more context, here's the code I'm working with: [CodeSandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-fire-bpqdep?file=/src/EditableTable/styledTable.tsx)

I would be immensely grateful if someone could lend a hand and assist me with this problem. Thank you in advance for your time and support!

Best regards,
Armando.